# slide transition from left to right and back

Tags: jquery-mobile

I work on a sample which I want to navigate from page1 to page2 from left to right, so I use `data-transition="slide"` and `data-direction="reverse"` in anchor tag. Actually it works fine, however, when I click back button on the browser it should back to page1 from right to left but still it back from left to right.

Although this scenario works fine when I don't use `data-direction="reverse"` it go to page2 and back to page1 correctly.

How I can I fix that? Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you're already using `reverse` and going back is reversed by default. you can override this with js `$('back_btn').on('click', function () { $.mobile.changePage($.mobile.activePage.prev('.ui-page'), { transition: 'slide', reverse: false });`

Comment: here's a demo http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/CKCjA/